# Passing user input to server for C++ compilation

Tags: javascript, c++, linux, bash, g++

I`m building an online c++ compiler for a school project. Right now I can send the c++ code a client writes in the web page to the server, use g++ to compile it, that run it and redirect output to a file and send the result right back to the client. The problem is my server stops working when the code contains something that asks for user input(ex: std::cin). What can I do to make a work around? I was thinkig of passing values with the code (lets say the client will have a separate box for input values), but i dont know how would i pass that input to the terminal.(i want to write a bash script that does something like this):

```
g++ tmp.cpp
./a.out
//here it stops because i should give it user input
```

Any idea?

edit: i want to use some values from a box
https://www.codechef.com/ide
this site is an example. (custom input)

Comment: if you specify the input format beforehand, you can save the input in a text file and use input redirection, e.g: `./a.out < input.txt`

Comment: @MartinYork yes, I know this is dangerous. I host my server on a virtual machine and all this is just for learning, I`m not planning to release a website like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use redirection as with pipe `|`:

```
cat input.txt | ./a.out
```

or

```
echo $user_input | ./a.out
```

Comment: oo, ok, I dindt think of using pipes. So now all i have to do is to make sure user_input have enough values, right?

Comment: With that, user input is no longer interactive, so without enough value, `std::cin` will return eof.

Comment: its been a while since i`ve worked with bash, so i forgot something so trivial. Thanks for helping me!